# call Oracle stored procedure using Spring's org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am developing application (spring framework 2.5 - old one). The task is to call oracle's stored procedure using 'org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure'

Strange thing is that - it compiles, executes, throws no errors - and returns null instead of real value.

My test procedure  (it is in a package) looks like:

```sql
procedure testprocedure(input1 IN varchar2,
  input2 IN varchar2,
  output1 OUT VARCHAR2,
  output2 OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
  output1 := 'return1';
  output2 := 'return2';
END testprocedure;
```

Java code is:

```
public class TestClass extends StoredProcedure {
public static final String input1 = "input1";
public static final String input2 = "input2";
public static final String output1 = "output1";
public static final String output2 = "output2";

public TestClass() {
    setSql("testpackage.testprocedure");
    setFunction(false);
    declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter(output1, Types.VARCHAR));
    declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter(output2, Types.VARCHAR));
    declareParameter(new SqlParameter(input1, Types.VARCHAR));
    declareParameter(new SqlParameter(input2, Types.VARCHAR));
}

public TestReturn getTestProcedureOUTs (String pinput1, String pinput2) {
    Map<String, Object> in = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    in.put( input1, pinput1);
    in.put( input2, pinput2);

    System.out.println("Calling " + getSql() + " with parameters: " + in);

    Map<String, Object> res = execute(in);
    System.out.println("output is " + res);
    return new TestReturn((String) res.get(output1), (String) res.get(output2));

}}
```

and the output from stdout is

```
output is {output2=null, output1=null}
```

I suspect this is somehow connected to windows version (windows 10)
java version (1.7)
Oracle driver (ojdbc6.jar)

or something else - to obvious to see it by myself.

Comment: already know the answer - but will leave this open for now, in case someone likes quizzes like this one. Hint is here "something else - to obvious to see it "

Comment: If you know the answer, then you should post that as an answer, it might help others. Nothing is as frustrating than to Google for a problem, get to an SO question without an answer, but only a comment by the OP that he fixed without further details.

Comment: I am sory. Thank you for this comment. Good point there.

Answer (score 2):

Order of declared parameters is important.

Parameters should be declared in the same order as they do appear in oracle procedure  or function.

In my case I had to reorder these parameters declaration in class constructor and put them like this:

```
public TestClass()    {
    setSql("testpackage.testprocedure");
    setFunction(false);
    declareParameter(new SqlParameter(input1, Types.VARCHAR));
    declareParameter(new SqlParameter(input2, Types.VARCHAR));
    declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter(output1, Types.VARCHAR));
    declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter(output2, Types.VARCHAR));
}
```

And this behavior is described in spring framework reference:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/object/StoredProcedure.html